# Triggering A SubDag

Tags: airflow

**EDITED**
*I have edited this question by considering the inputs from @tobi6*

I copied the subdag operator from Airflow source code

Source code: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/subdag_operator.py

I modified a few things in the execute method. The changes were made to trigger the SubDag and wait until the SubDag completes execution. The trigger is working great but the tasks are not being executed (DAG is in the **running/Green** state while the tasks are in the **null/White** state).

Please refer below for the changes I made:

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.models import BaseOperator, Pool
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
from airflow.utils.db import provide_session
from airflow.utils.state import State
from airflow.executors import GetDefaultExecutor
from time import sleep
import logging

from datetime import datetime


class SubDagOperator(BaseOperator):

    template_fields = tuple()
    ui_color = '#555'
    ui_fgcolor = '#fff'

    @provide_session
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            subdag,
            executor=GetDefaultExecutor(),
            *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Yo dawg. This runs a sub dag. By convention, a sub dag's dag_id
        should be prefixed by its parent and a dot. As in `parent.child`.

        :param subdag: the DAG object to run as a subdag of the current DAG.
        :type subdag: airflow.DAG
        :param dag: the parent DAG
        :type subdag: airflow.DAG
        """
        import airflow.models
        dag = kwargs.get('dag') or airflow.models._CONTEXT_MANAGER_DAG
        if not dag:
            raise AirflowException('Please pass in the `dag` param or call '
                                   'within a DAG context manager')
        session = kwargs.pop('session')
        super(SubDagOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # validate subdag name
        if dag.dag_id + '.' + kwargs['task_id'] != subdag.dag_id:
            raise AirflowException(
                "The subdag's dag_id should have the form "
                "'{{parent_dag_id}}.{{this_task_id}}'. Expected "
                "'{d}.{t}'; received '{rcvd}'.".format(
                    d=dag.dag_id, t=kwargs['task_id'], rcvd=subdag.dag_id))

        # validate that subdag operator and subdag tasks don't have a
        # pool conflict
        if self.pool:
            conflicts = [t for t in subdag.tasks if t.pool == self.pool]
            if conflicts:
                # only query for pool conflicts if one may exist
                pool = (
                    session
                    .query(Pool)
                    .filter(Pool.slots == 1)
                    .filter(Pool.pool == self.pool)
                    .first()
                )
                if pool and any(t.pool == self.pool for t in subdag.tasks):
                    raise AirflowException(
                        'SubDagOperator {sd} and subdag task{plural} {t} both '
                        'use pool {p}, but the pool only has 1 slot. The '
                        'subdag tasks will never run.'.format(
                            sd=self.task_id,
                            plural=len(conflicts) > 1,
                            t=', '.join(t.task_id for t in conflicts),
                            p=self.pool
                        )
                    )

        self.subdag = subdag
        self.executor = executor

    def execute(self, context):
        dag_run = self.subdag.create_dagrun(
            conf=context['dag_run'].conf,
            state=State.RUNNING,
            execution_date=context['execution_date'],
            run_id='trig__' + str(datetime.utcnow()),
            external_trigger=True
        )


        while True:
            if dag_run.get_state() == State.FAILED or dag_run.get_state() == State.SUCCESS:
                break
            else:
                sleep(10)
                continue
```

Below is the code that shows how I'm using the same

```
from airflow import DAG
from operators.sd_operator import SubDagOperator  # My SubDag Operator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import logging
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2017, 7, 17),
        'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
        'email_on_failure': False,
        'email_on_retry': False,
    }


def print_dag_details(**kwargs):
    logging.info(str(kwargs['dag_run'].conf))


with DAG('example_dag', schedule_interval=None, catchup=False, default_args=default_args) as dag:
    task_1 = SubDagOperator(
        subdag=sub_dag_func('example_dag', 'sub_dag_1'),
        task_id='sub_dag_1'
    )

    task_2 = SubDagOperator(
        subdag=sub_dag_func('example_dag', 'sub_dag_2'),
        task_id='sub_dag_2',
    )

    print_kwargs = PythonOperator(
        task_id='print_kwargs',
        python_callable=print_dag_details,
        provide_context=True
    )

    print_kwargs >> task_1 >> task_2
```

Any information you provide would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah, don't do this. With the new airflow design, it makes a lot of sense to be using task groups: https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-taskgroups-all-you-need-to-know/#:~:text=A%20TaskGroup%20is%20a%20collection,grouping%20feature%20in%20the%20UI.

Answer (score -2):

It is a bit hard to understand your question without context.

"I copied the subdag operator and modified a few things in the execute method."

- From where was this copied?

"The trigger is working great ..."

- How does this look like?

There are a few things I saw in the code:

- It might be helpful to add assigned fields to the function call of sub_dag_func, e.g. `sub_dag_func(subdag='parent_dag'...)`.
- In the binary shift definition, used to set upstream / downstream there are tasks defined I cannot find in the DAG (`df_job_1`, `df_job_2`). This might be connected to SubDAGs (haven't looked into them yet).
- The name of the sub dag seems inconsistent with the comment in the code saying `By convention, a sub dag's dag_id should be prefixed by its parent and a dot` but it is `sub_dag_1`, `sub_dag_2`

Comment: I copied the code of subdag operator from airflow source code. The operator is creating a DagRun object which is updating the dag status to running with a new trigger information (I see the running status in the Airflow UI with new trigger information). However, The tasks within the DAG are not picked up by Scheduler/Worker. Thus No status or execution is carried out.